# React-Native how to clear inner navigation stack?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stack-navigator

I'm new to react-native and am developing an app which has bottom tab navigation.For implementing this , I've used **react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs** ,which is working perfectly fine.Like I have 3 screens ,say Home,Profile and About in the bottom tab navigator.But in the **Home** screen I have multiple screens flow to be implemented.For that I used **Stack Navigator** ,which is also working fine. So my app flow is like `Home-> Screen1-> Screen2-> Screen3`
Where I'm facing problem is that suppose I'm on Screen3 and then I switch to **Profile** screen from bottom navigation ,and then again switch to **Home** screen ,

> I should be able to see Home Screen there but currently it shows
>   Screen3

It is where I left.What should I do ?
Following is my code

App.js (which contains bottom navigation)

```
export default BottomTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
{
Home: {
  screen: HomeRoutes,
  },
},
Profile: {
  screen: ProfileScreen,
},
About: {
  screen: AboutScreen,
 },
},
{
initialRouteName: 'Home',
},
);
```

HomeRoutes.js

```
export default createStackNavigator(
{
  Home:{
     screen: Home,
   },
  Screen1: {
     screen: Screen1,
   },
Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2,
  },
Screen3: {
  screen: Screen3,
   },
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
},
);
```

Or maybe can I do something like this ,when I navigate to screen1 from home screen, the bottom tab navigation is not shown to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to see the home screen again when you press the home tab again. Then this can solve the problem by comparing the values on the current screen when you press the Home tab again.

### last Screen in `HomeRoute`

```js
import { StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
...
let chk = false
...
 componentDidUpdate(){
    if (!chk){
      chk = true // Change value when rendering screen
    } else {
      //The popToTop action takes you back to the first screen in the stack, dismissing all the others.
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop()); 
      chk = false //Initialization
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The screen names of `BottomTabNavigator` and `StackNavigator` should not be the same.

You can change this code like below.

```
export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    CHome:{
      screen: Home,
    },
    Screen1: {
      screen: Screen1,
    },
    Screen2: {
      screen: Screen2,
    },
    Screen3: {
      screen: Screen3,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'CHome',
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Your code is fine, thing is when you navigate from Home -> Screen 3 to say Profile the navigation stack has the history of Screen 3 being the last route on stack, so when you head back to Home it will show you Screen 3 not Screen 1.

### Solution

A simple approach to this would before you call `this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')` you can clear the stacked routes, like so:

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

**Note:** Am not sure what version of `react-navigation` you are using so check the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/stack-actions.html#reset) for the right version and right usage, but this should give you an idea of how to do it.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Where do I call this ? `this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);`

Comment: on whatever function you are using before calling `this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')`

Comment: But I'm not calling the Profile stack `this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')` by this.It is in the bottom tab navigation stack

Comment: can you add a sample of the code part you are calling the `navigate('Profile')` to the question so i can show you what you can do

Comment: Sure ,but the Profile screen is called from the bottom tab navigator stack.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to reset navigation:

```
navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: 'HomePage' }] })
```